# Windows Phone 8 html camera upload capture="camera"

Tags: html, windows-phone-8

I have an app written for iOS that uses some special html attribute to allow iOS to load in the photo library.  I'm wondering if Windows Phone has a similar capability or function as this doesn't work.  Most of the documentation I found uses XAML to other languages to do this.  Maybe a Phonegap plugin might work?

```
<input name="t1" class="imgupload" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Comment: If [Mobile HTML5](http://mobilehtml5.org/) is to be believed, it looks like support for the "HTML Media Capture" feature is missing from mobile IE10.

Comment: @Blynn Did you find a solution for this feature?